# If I don't trust insurance companies, what alternative options exist to counter a potential earthquake?

Tags: united-states, insurance

I live in Seattle which is [well known](https://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2015/07/20/the-really-big-one) for potentially having a huge earthquake sometime in the next 1,000 years. I would like to protect my property against such a catastrophic outcome, but at the same time I have zero trust in private insurance due to the recent [COVID insurance stories](https://www.bizjournals.com/houston/news/2020/04/08/star-cinema-grill-owner-sues-insurance-co-after.html). Are there alternative options available to me that would pay out a big sum in case the "big one" does hit, but are otherwise worthless? Or perhaps some sort of an insurance on the insurance that is well know to pay out quickly, ideally evidenced via their quick payouts during the COVID crisis?

Comment: Could someone explain the downvotes? Its a serious money issue and you can look into the recent COVID insurance stories to understand my concerns.

Comment: I can't tell what you're actually asking for. It sounds like you're asking for insurance that isn't private insurance—does that mean you're only interested in insurance that's sold by the government? Or, it kind of sounds like you're asking for a contract that pays out in the event of a disaster, but isn't insurance. But that's impossible because that type of contract is what the word "insurance" *means*. Or it seems like you're asking for insurance which is sold by a company that doesn't sell insurance; that's obviously impossible too.

Comment: @TannerSwett mutual insurance is the only other option, since -- even though it's private insurance, the company is owned by the policyholders.

Comment: @TannerSwett either some sort of a government option or an insurance for the insurance that would add a safety pillow

Comment: The OP is correct in distrusting private insurance. Many, many businesses took out business interruption insurance and the insurance  industry is trying to avoid paying hundreds of millions of dollars to businesses forced to close because of the pandemic. It's now in the courts.  Meanwhile, the businesses paid the premiums but got nothing in return, other than out of business.

Comment: I cannot see the slightest reason anyone would downvote this?

Comment: I was going to suggest a bet at a local bookmaker, betting that there will be an earthquake in the next year.  But I don't think that's even legal in your state.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your best option is to move somewhere that doesn't have an earthquake risk.

If you don't trust insurance companies, then make life choices to avoid all risks that you can.

Comment: I have to accept this as the best and most obvious answer :)

Answer (score 6):

Self insurance is probably your best option here. Put a certain amount of money into a separate savings account every month and in case of a damaging earthquake, use that to recoup your losses. Yes, the "payout" won't be as high as that of a standard insurance policy, but by self insuring you're forgoing the risk pooling that comes with many policyholders paying into a fund (the insurance company) and only a subset of them receiving a payout.

Comment: Some  physicians in higher risk specialties self insure because their malpractice  insurance costs six figures but self insurance isn't practical for typical homeowners because whatever they can save won't add up to scratch if their home is demolished.

Answer (score 0):

As MichaelA answers, the only alternative to insurance is **self-insurance**.

• This is not a whacky idea. Note that it is fairly common that corporations "don't like" insurance so they self-insure certain risks:  i.e., they judge financially that it's better to self-insure.

• A simple real-world example, I have never in my life bought "comprehensive" car insurance on any vehicle, anywhere in the world.  {Obviously you should, and of course in most jurisdictions legally have to, buy 3rd-party insurance.†}  Hence if I ever have a car stolen, burst in to flames or the like ... it's a straight loss. But on the other hand I have saved all those premiums on all those cars all those years. (If you're wondering, the outcome is I'm wildly ahead; I've never, ever had a car stolen, burst in to flames, etc - even once.)

## In answer to the question at the end...

> Or perhaps some sort of an insurance on the insurance that is well know to pay out quickly, ideally evidenced via their quick payouts during the COVID crisis?

Yes, in the US "Aflac" exists for exactly that purpose:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pj3B9PFNvZQ go to 0:15
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SaVTrV0Wsew go to 0:21

(Roll tide!)

---

† *Of course, if you get a car loan, you are forced to get comprehensive insurance by the loan company.*

Comment: Afiac seems to be focused on healthcare insurance though.

Comment: Self insurance only works when you can afford the loss.  Most people can't afford to rebuild their house after an earthquake destroys it.

Comment: "*corporations "don't like" insurance so they self-insure certain risks.*" Corporations like insurance fine enough; they self-insure when they think they can do it cheaper.

Comment: hi Ron - right, that's literally what the sentence says!  "ie, they judge financially that it's better to self-insure."

Comment: @JonathanReez - true; (I'm not sure what else they do) ...  but it was the only example I know of of the interesting concept you raise.

Comment: @gaefan - well the idea of self-insurance is you set aside money rather than paying the insurance premiums (that's what businesses do when they self-insure); in the specific case of real estate (say you own it outright) recall you can easily get a mortage to rebuild it if your "stockpile" has not built up enough. NOte that houses fall apart and have to be rebuilt regularly anyway; it plays in to it. (Also note that, typically folks have a mortgage on a house - so the entire question is moot; the bank owns it and they force you to have total insurance, so it's not really relevant.)

Comment: @Fattie even if the bank forces insurance, you'll still be responsible if they end up stalling after an earthquake

Comment: Jonathon - yes, I suppose so, true.  As Bob.B. mentioned in a comment, self-insurance for a house is often impractical due to the sums involved.  (In contrast my "car" example, suits self-insurance.)  (Indeed, I've certainly never self-insured a piece of real-estate!!!)